# HTML data get from $http GET is not showing properly in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I have defined a controller like this:

```
app.controller("home", function ($scope, $http, $common) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: '/posts/loadData'
    }).then(function (response) {
        //console.clear()
        if (typeof response.data.posts != 'undefined') {
            console.log(response.data.posts);
            $scope.posts = $common.arrangePosts(response.data.posts);
        }
    });
})
```

and a service to arrange data:

```
app.service('$common', function ($timeout, $sce, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
    var that = this;
    this.arrangePosts = function (rawPosts) {
        var posts = [];
        
        $.each(rawPosts, function (key, value) {
            posts.push({
                          postId: value.postId, 
                          postLink: '/post/' + that.cleanString(value.title) + '/' + value.postId, 
                          title: value.title, 
                          summary: $sce.trustAsHtml(value.summary)
                       });
        });

        return posts;
    }
});
```

using values in HTML like this:

```
<div class="widget fullwidth post-single">
        <h4 class="widget-title">Latest</h4>
        <div class="widget-content">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
                    <h4 class="list-title"><a href="{{post.postLink}}">{{post.title}}</a></h4>
                    {{post.summary}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Data coming from server in JSON form:

```
Object { postId="4",  title="asdf",  summary="<p>asdf</p>"}
```

but all the HTML tags are printing on my page as it is (like a text) in summary.

In many SO posts people suggested to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` but it's not working for me. What can I try next?

Comment: Are you injecting html with angular stuff into the page? Maybe show an example of what the html looks like?

Comment: i have updated the question please check..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```html
<div ng-bind-html='post.summary'></div>
```

Comment: This is working and i have implemented this on full post view page but here i don't want to include unnecessary elements. If there is another way u know for my current structure please tell.

Comment: @Ritesh you can use ngTransclude: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: there is no other solution available except ng-bind-html. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this over a directive. Did you know, that you can use JQuery Lite inside AngularJS to manipulate the DOM?

Here a quick example:

```
angular.module("PostsDirective",[])
.directive("posts", function($sce){
return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        //the HTML you want to show 
        var post = "<div>hello world</div>";

        var posts = [post,post,post,post];

        //iterating through the list (_.each is a function from underscore.js)
        _.each(posts, function(element){
            //if you want to save the trusted html string in a var you can do this with getTrustedHtml
            //see the docs
            var safeHtml =  $sce.getTrustedHtml($sce.trustAsHtml(element));

            //and here you can use JQuery Lite. It appends the html string to the DOM
            //$element refers to the directive element in the DOM
            $element.append(safeHtml);
        });
    }
};
});
```

And the html

```
   <posts></posts>
```

This also pretty nice for the readability for your HTML code. And you can use it everywhere on your page.

BTW:
As i can see, you get the HTML elements directly from a REST-Service. Why don't you get just the data and insert it into the ng-repeat? If you transfer all the HTML you get a pretty high overhead if you have loads of data.

Comment: in my code am getting articles with proper formatting so how can anyone get this kind of data with html tags..??

Comment: So you can't change the code on the server side to JSON because it's a external resource? I'm sorry, I don't know if I understood you right.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and its throwing this error : Error: [$sce:itype] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/$sce/itype?p0=html

For your second comment, i can change code on server but my data are articles with proper formatting that's why i need to fetch data with html tags

Comment: i have updated question with JSON response. Please check..!!